# Post order = rand - not working in one category (wp_query)

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got problem with display random post.
I use this loop:

```
 <?php 
    remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');
      $loop = new WP_Query( array( orderby => 'rand', 'cat' => '259', 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) ); ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

Loop doesn't work in one category. Why? In the others everything is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
<?php
remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'cat'            => 259,
    'posts_per_page' => 1
));

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

you've set `orderby` without `''` quotes. Also remove them from the category id, this needs to be a number (integer), not a string.

Comment: You are right, but without quotes also works. I don't know why it doesn't work in such one category (259)

Comment: Is your category empty? Also I noticed the quotes on the category, remove those and it should work.

Comment: No, category have 14 posts. I noticed it have sorting own set by the plugin. Maybe it block random display. Can I disable it in this loop?

Comment: Hmm...I find the solution. This category cotains sub cattegories - I attach it to loop, and now it works. Thank you for your help.